# Does gcc support -static-libgcc with -fexceptions?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, pthreads

My program crashes with a segfault trying to unwind the stack.  Is this a gcc bug or is the combination of options `-fexceptions` and `-static-libgcc` not allowed?

The crash doesn't happen if:

- `-static-libgcc` is omitted
- `-fexceptions` is omitted
- <s>Compile and link are done in a single step</s>
- `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` are omitted
- Compilation is done using `g++` or `gcc -x g++` (*)

I have tried this on gcc 4.8.4 and 4.8.5.

*(*) This doesn't work for one of our custom build environments based on gcc 4.2.3.  Yet for a different version of the build environment also based on gcc 4.2.3 the crash doesn't happen at all!*

### Test case

```
/*
 * thread_crash.c: Test case for thread unwinder crash bug.
 *
 * Compile (with native or V6p3, 32 or 64 bit) using:
 *    gcc -o thread_crash.o -c thread_crash.c -ggdb -Wall -pthread -fexceptions
 *    g++ -o thread_crash thread_crash.o -ggdb -Wall -lpthread -static-libgcc
 * 
 * Expected behaviour: No output.
 * Observed behaviour: Outputs "Aborted (core dumped)".
 */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void cleanup(void *ptr)
{
}

void *child(void *ptr)
{
  pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t foo;
  pthread_create(&foo, NULL, child, NULL);
  pthread_join(foo, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

### Backtrace from gdb

```
#0  0x00007ffff72271f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff72288e8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004031be in _Unwind_SetGR ()
#3  0x000000000040587a in __gcc_personality_v0 ()
#4  0x00007ffff6feba14 in ?? () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff6febd64 in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff7bcd240 in __pthread_unwind () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff7bc7e35 in pthread_exit () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x0000000000400a97 in child (ptr=0x0) at thread_crash.c:46
#9  0x00007ffff7bc6e25 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff72ea34d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: FWIW this also crashes with Clang. It doesn't crash with either if we build the file as C++ (via `-x c++` or by renaming the file).

Comment: Also for me the `??` location in the backtrace is in `_Unwind_ForcedUnwind_Phase2`

Comment: Usually `-fexceptions` and `-frtti` are both specified. But it is not clear to me it would help. I kind of feel like `libgcc` needs to be built with the same options (assuming it is not).

Comment: @jww According to GCC, `-frtti` is not allowed for C code (which this is compiled as)

Answer (score 1):

When compiling with `-fexception`, `pthread_exit()` throws a `___forced_unwind` exception to force all functions to be unwinded, this guarantees automatic storage (aka *stack*) cleanup. This is because `pthread_exit()` is designed not to return. From [`man pthread_exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html):

> This function does not return to the caller.

On the other hand, according to [`man pthread_cleanup_push`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html):

> POSIX.1 says that the effect of using return, break, continue, or
>          goto to prematurely leave a block bracketed pthread_cleanup_push()
>          and pthread_cleanup_pop() is undefined.  Portable applications should
>          avoid doing this.

POSIX does not mention C++ exceptions since POSIX only care about C, but this is an educated guess that throwing an exception between `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` results in an undefined behaviour.